# Apply Lambda Function to Multiple Columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm looking to include multiple columns in my lambda function, but am running into key issues which shouldn't be right. I am looking for this line to create a new column that says IF "Decision" is present within the Task, then flag it as a Decision. Otherwise, IF "Milestone" is present in "Projects", mark it as a Milestone. Otherwise, leave it as the current Task Type.

```
today['New_Type'] = today[['Task','Projects','Type'].apply(lambda x,y,z: "Decision" if "Decision" in x else "Milestone" if "Milestone" in y else z)
```

Any ideas how to adjust this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample (made up or otherwise) data with your example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: What's currently happening, and how is it different than what you intend?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what you described does not require a new column. In fact, a new column seems to not benefit you at all, since all the rows of your DataFrame would be assigned with a similar flag to be determined based on the availability of "Decision" in other columns. That would be helpful if you could elaborate.

Comment: `apply` always send one value - single value for single column (`Series`), single row for more columns - so you have to use `lambda row:` and later `row['Task']`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to debug if you use a regular, named function. Be sure to specify the `axis` argument when you call `apply`. The function you write will need to take a single argument that is a tuple of the three column values, so best unpack them immediately for readability:

```py
import pandas as pd

def task_type(row):
    task, project, old_type = row
    if 'decision' in task.lower():
        return 'Decision'
    if 'milestone' in project.lower():
        return 'Milestone'
    return old_type


today = pd.DataFrame({'Task': ['Make a decision.', 
                               'Do something else.',
                               'Write a function.'],
                      'Projects': ['alpha', 'Milestone 7',
                                   'gamma'],
                      'Type': ['old 1', 'old 2', 'old 3']})

today['New_Type'] = today.apply(task_type, axis=1)
today
```

```
    Task                Projects     Type   New_Type
0   Make a decision.    alpha        old 1  Decision
1   Do something else.  Milestone 7  old 2  Milestone
2   Write a function.   gamma        old 3  old 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `Series.apply` (hidden loop) and consider a vectorized, conditional logic approach using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
today['New_Type'] = np.where(
    today['Task'].str.contains('Decision', regex = False),
    'Decision',
    np.where(
        today['Task'].str.contains('Milestone', regex = False),
        'Milestone',
        today['Task']
    )
)

today['New_Type'] = np.select(
    condlist = [
        today['Task'].str.contains('Decision', regex = False), 
        today['Task'].str.contains('Milestone', regex = False)
    ],
    choicelist = ['Decision', 'Milestone'],
    default = today['Task']
)
```